# restricting past dates on datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datepicker

I'm not having problem restricting some of my `datetimepicker` but this one is persistent, I'm trying to do this in `angularjs`, and the `datetimepicker` is inside the datatable, I'm setting it like this:

```
         {
            data: "next_action_date",
            name: "next_action_date",
            render: (data, type, row, meta)->
              initValue = data
              if data
                initValue = "'" + data + "'"
              if row.is_editable
                return '<div class="input-control text" data-role="datepicker"
                           ng-controller="ContactDateCtrl"
                           ng-init="init(' + row['pk'] + ', ' + initValue + ')" data-format="mmmm d, yyyy">
                          <input type="text" ng-model="contactDate" ng-change="onChange()">
                          <button class="button"><span class="mif-calendar"></span></button>
                      </div>';
              else
                return data;
          }
```

so this is a column in `datatable` where I've putting `datetimepicker`, so in the controller I'm doing something like this:

```
(function() {
  var app;

  app = angular.module('cms.sales');

  app.controller('ContactDateCtrl', [
    '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
      var nextContactDateUpdateFailed, nextContactDateUpdateSuccess;
      $scope.contactDate = null;
      $scope.leadContactPk = null;
      $scope.init = function(leadContactPk, nextContactDate) {
        nextContactDate = new Date();
        $scope.leadContactPk = leadContactPk;
        if (nextContactDate) {
          return $scope.contactDate = nextContactDate.getFullYear() + '-' + (nextContactDate.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + nextContactDate.getDate();
        } else {
          return $scope.contactDate = "";
        }
      };
      $scope.onChange = function() {
        var data;
        data = {
          contact_date: $scope.contactDate,
          lead_pk: $scope.leadContactPk
        };
        return $http.post("/sales/update_contact_date/", data).then(nextContactDateUpdateSuccess, nextContactDateUpdateFailed);
      };
      nextContactDateUpdateSuccess = function() {
        return ClientNotifications.showNotification("Success", "Next communication date was updated", "success");
      };
      return nextContactDateUpdateFailed = function() {
        return ClientNotifications.showNotification("Alert", "Failed to update next communication date", "alert");
      };
    }
  ]);

}).call(this);
```

Now this does not restrict my `datetimepicker` it is just returning this time format `2017-5-23`, and I'm not sure what else to do so is there anything else I could do so this restriction will work, I'm using [metroui](https://metroui.org.ua/datepicker.html) `datetimepicker` in my project, can anyone help me restrict this properly, thank you.

Comment: Why can't you use `angular-material` datepicker?

Comment: because we are using this datepicker in the project -.-

Comment: Do you just want to restrict past dates from particular day?

Comment: @Mr_Perfect, look at this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/30e371ou/5/) example, this is what I want, it's working on some other `datepicker` in the project, note that the time needs to me in this format `Jan 13, 2017`, and this is that `metroui-datepicker`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add format

```
$(function(){
   $("#datepicker").datepicker({
   format: 'mmmm d, yyyy',
    minDate:new Date(Date.now()-(86400000 * n)) // just for min date and 'n' is the number of previous days to be allowed
   });
});
```

or customize the ng-model of input.

Just do something like this in the if condition

```
var tempDate = nextContactDate.toString().split(' ');
tempDate = tempDate[1] + " " + tempDate[2] + ", " + tempDate[3];
$scope.tempDate = tempDate;
$scope.contactDate = nextContactDate;
```

If you change the date to string, you may loose to handle in the controller. So, store it in a temporary `$scope.tempDate` to display in the view and use the main variable i.e., `$scope.contactDate` to do the logic.

Make sure that `ng-model` of input should be `$scope.tempDate`

**First choice is better**